# Summing the max values when grouping other then exact

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I will explain step by step. I'm trying to get one single integer value for a certain key set.

So let's say that i have the following map function

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.key1, doc.key2, doc.key3], doc.integerValue);
}
```

the doc.IntegerValue in this case is a sequence. So let's say that someone makes 0,10,20,30 progress and after that he starts on a new sessionId with once again 0,10,20,30,40.

Now i was trying to reach the following. 
1) When doing a group exact it should ouptut the max integerValue found.(first 30, second 40)
2) When doing a group on level 2 it should output the sum according to the max values on scenario 1. So that i can count the total value. So let's assume that key2 and key1 where the same in both examples, it would give me 70. 
3) when doing a group on level 1 it should also give 70. as it are the same 2 rows as in the last scenario.

The _stats reduce function does not do the job as it only gives the max of the whole group or the sum of the whole group and my request is a combination of both.

besides that i know, i have the option to leaf the grouping thing out, and then select with startKey and endKey, but i want to check if it is possible with the grouping option.

Thanks in advance for any  ideas.!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in stats, why don't you just output the single highest value of `integerValue`* in your view and use `_sum` as the reduce function?

```
// map function
function(doc) {
  if(!doc.integerValue || !(doc.integerValue instanceof Array)) return
  return ([doc.key1, doc.key2, doc.key3], doc.integerValue.sort().reverse()[0])
}
// reduce function
_sum
```

This will mean

- `group_level=exact` will output the highest value of the sequence
- `group_level=2` will output the sum of those single highest values of each sequence
- `group_level=1` will do the same.

*Assuming `integerValue` is an array -- I wasn't 100% sure from your question.